# What to use for vertical spacing in web hybrid mobile views?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, hybrid-mobile-app

Some devices like the iPhone SE are very small so using EM for margins that look nice in bigger devices will mess up that view.

Should I use percentage or VH instead?

Comment: Why not continue to use `em`s and apply a media query to make `font-size` smaller on a root element for displays under a specific width?

Comment: I guess a better question is should I be using EMs for vertical spacing in hybrid views? @JonUleis